# Laravel Query- When carrying out a query Laravel seems to be adding ?/spaces between each letter

Tags: mysql, laravel

select `code` from `country_code` where `country` = '?U?n?i?t?e?d? ?K?i?n?g?d?o?m' order by `country` asc limit 1

```
public function location_test(){

   $locations = DB::table('accesses')
                ->select('country' ,DB::raw('count(*) as count'))
                ->join('ip2c_cache', 'accesses.ip', '=', 'ip2c_cache.ip')
                ->where('showcase_id', 5613)->groupby('country')
                ->get();

    $mapData = "";
    $locationData = array();

   foreach ($locations as $location) {

        $code = DB::table('country_code')
                    ->select('code')->where('country', $location->country)
                    ->orderBy('country')
                    ->first();

         $mapData = $mapData . '"' . $code->id . '":"' . $location->count . '",';
     }
  return $mapData;
}
```

Comment: what is the text encoding  of your database? what is the encoding set in your connection to the database?

Comment: Collation is utf8_general_ci and the type is varchar(2)

Answer (score 0):

Problem was fixed when I changes the Collation of the database